# Get the duration of the overlapping intervals

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, duration, overlapping

I have a list of TimeSpans and I want to get the duration of all the overlapping TimeSpans. (see image)

[image]

In this case the duration must be 2,5 hours and not 3 hours. Does someone have an idea?

Example:

[image]

"Administratief" is an appointment of 40 minutes. "Tafel dekken" is an appointment of 30 minutes but it overlap "Administratief" zo the duration is 40 minutes + 10 minutes of "Tafel dekken". And you have "Prolongeren" of 30 minutes so in this case the duration must be 80 minutes.

Comment: So in your example the result will be 30 minutes? What will be the result if there is a third timespan from 9:45 to 10:30?

Comment: Yes I know. It are actually Appointments (DevExpress) so they have a StartTime and an EndTime. The duration of the StartTime and EndTime is a TimeSpan object.

Comment: @Steve The result must be still 2,5 hours

Comment: I have a class library that would suit this perfectly here: https://intervals.codeplex.com/ - You would basically construct all those apppointments as `Interval<DateTime>`, put them in a collection and run `.Slice()` on the collection and you would get non-overlapping slices out, the total of which would be your 2.5 hours. Each slice would also link back to the intervals that went into it. In your case you would get one slice from 8:30 to 9:15, one from 9:15 to 9:30, 9:30 to 10:00, 10:00 to 10:15 and 10:15 to 11:00.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I will give it a try ;). Thank you

Comment: ChrisF's answer is much easier if you're just interested in the total time, not the actual different overlapping "slices". If you need more advanced handling later you can always go back and look at my class library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple but inefficient algorithm (`O(n²)`) that does not require a sorted list.
First, all overlapping intervals are merged, then the interval lengths are summed up (scroll down):

```
struct TimeRange
{
    DateTime Start;
    DateTime End;

    public TimeRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return End-Start;
        }
    }

    public static bool Overlap(TimeRange tr1, TimeRange tr2)
    {
        return (tr2.Start <= tr1.End && tr1.Start <= tr2.End);
    }

    public static TimeRange Merge(TimeRange tr1, TimeRange tr2)
    {
        return new TimeSpan(
            (tr1.Start < tr2.Start) ? tr1.Start : tr2.Start,
            (tr1.End > tr2.End) ? tr1.End : tr2.End
        );
    }
}



List<TimeRange> timeRanges; // A *copy* of your data list

for(int i = 0; i < timeRanges.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < timeRanges.Count; j++)
    {
        if(TimeRange.Overlap(timeRanges[i],timeRanges[j])
        {
            timeRanges[i] = TimeRange.Merge(timeRanges[i],timeRanges[j]);
            timeRanges.RemoveAt(j);
            j--;
        }
    }
}

TimeSpan totalDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;
foreach(TimeRange in timeRanges)
{
    totalDuration += timeRanges.Duration;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the start times as well as the durations you can do this by getting the minimum start time and the maximum end time and then calculate the difference:

```
DateTime minStart = timeList.Min(l => l.StartTime);
DateTime maxEnd = timeList.Max(l => l.EndTime);

TimeSpan duration = maxEnd - minStart;
```

If you don't have the end time directly then the `EndTime` property will have to be derived from the `StartTime` and `Duration`:

```
public DateTime EndTime
{
    get { return this.StartTime.Add(this.Duration); }
}
```

This will get the overall duration of the appointments and doesn't account for cases where there's a gap in the appointments. You will need to first process the list into sub lists where the appointments overlap or are contiguous. Something like this pseudo code:

```
var orderedAppointments = appointments.OrderBy(a => a.StartTime);
foreach (var appointment in orderedAppointments)
{
    if (first appointment)
        add to new sub list and add sub list to list of lists
    else if (appointment.StartTime <= subList.Max(s => s.EndTime))
        add to existing sub list
    else
        add to new sub list and add sub list to list of lists
}
```

Then you can get the overall duration of each sub list using the initial code.

Comment: There could be holes between the appointments, or perhaps not, he says "overlapping intervals".

Comment: @AbusiveVids - I've added the algorithm you need to get the groups of contiguous/overlapping appointments.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks, I will check it out. I think this must be the solution.